# Update Label in Table View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a table view where is showed the name of every element of a database. One field is the price of that element.

I use this UILabel to show the sum of all the prices, and it works perfectly.

[image]

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    conto = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:0];
    shoppingListItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadDataFromDb];
    [self sortListArray];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    if ([conto intValue] < 0) {
        walletLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else { walletLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor]; }
    walletLabel.text =  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Saldo: %@€", [conto stringValue]];
}
```

"conto" variable is calculate inside "loadDataFromDB" method.

I would like to update it every time I delete a row from the table.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Just call your update routine in your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: so I should reload the table from the database instead of just reloading it from the MutableArray?
I have this [tableView reloadData] at the end of that method. But looks like it's not enough...

Comment: Ok, i solved creating a method where I update the routine directly from the Array, and calling this method where you said. Thanks man.